# sparql dbpedia.org only goal in fiorentina

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

Is there some way to obtain only goals that soccer players scored in Fiorentina with dbpedia.org SPARQL endpoint? I tried the following query, but unfortunately I obtain goals for each season.

```sql
select * where {
  ?player a dbo:SoccerPlayer.
  ?player dbo:team <http://dbpedia.org/resource/ACF_Fiorentina>.
  ?player dbp:position <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Forward_(association_football)>.
  ?player dbp:goals ?goal.
}
limit 10000
```

Comment: Are you trying to add up all of the goals for each player?  The data is modeled with `goal` as a literal, so there isn't a way to find which year the goals were scored in.

Comment: @scotthenninger The players are also related to a bunch of "career station" entities, which do correspond to time periods, teams, and goals, so I think this information *is* accessible.  I've added an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do this.  If you browse the [data for Silva](http://dbpedia.org/page/Santiago_Silva), you'll see a number of career stations, e.g., [station 12](http://dbpedia.org/page/Santiago_Silva__12), each of which has a number of goals.  That means you can do:

```sql
select * where {
  ?player a dbo:SoccerPlayer ; 
          dbp:position <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Forward_(association_football)> ;
          dbo:careerStation ?station .
  ?station dbo:numberOfGoals ?goals ;
           dbo:team dbr:ACF_Fiorentina .
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20*%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fplayer%20a%20dbo%3ASoccerPlayer%20%3B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbp%3Aposition%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FForward_%28association_football%29%3E%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3AcareerStation%20%3Fstation%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fstation%20dbo%3AnumberOfGoals%20%3Fgoals%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3Ateam%20dbr%3AACF_Fiorentina%20.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Of course, a player might have multiple stations on the same team, so you'd still want to aggregate over each player and sum the goals:

```sql
select ?player (sum(?goals) as ?totalGoals) where {
  ?player a dbo:SoccerPlayer ; 
          dbp:position <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Forward_(association_football)> ;
          dbo:careerStation ?station .
  ?station dbo:numberOfGoals ?goals ;
           dbo:team dbr:ACF_Fiorentina .
}
group by ?player
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fplayer%20%28sum%28%3Fgoals%29%20as%20%3FtotalGoals%29%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fplayer%20a%20dbo%3ASoccerPlayer%20%3B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbp%3Aposition%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FForward_%28association_football%29%3E%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3AcareerStation%20%3Fstation%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fstation%20dbo%3AnumberOfGoals%20%3Fgoals%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3Ateam%20dbr%3AACF_Fiorentina%20.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Agroup%20by%20%3Fplayer%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

### Related

There are some other questions that involve querying career stations that might be useful:

- [SPARQL - query a property and return results for a related property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29727984/1281433) (This is about getting goals, too.  Does this happen to be a class assignment or something?)
- [Obtaining start and end date from a DBPedia CareerStation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35173122/1281433)
- [How to build correct SPARQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27721834/1281433)